# how can i compare the first and last / second and second last elements of the string in java script

Tags: javascript

how can i compare the first and last / second and second last elements of the string in java script

ex: we take in 102201
compare 1 and 1
0 and 0
2 and 2
it's want to any string.

if another ex: element

then 
check e and t
l and n
e and e
m forgot it.

my code like

```
function check() {
  var input = document.getElementById("check").value;

  var inputcount = "";

  if ((input.length) % 2 === 0) {
    inputcount = (input.length) / 2;
  } else {
    inputcount = (input.length - 1) / 2;
  }
  for (var x = 0; x < inputcount; x++) {
    //....
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract the `x` from the array length to get the last character

```js
function check() {
  var input = document.getElementById("check").value;

  var inputcount = Math.floor(input.length / 2);

  for (var x = 0; x < inputcount; x++) {
    snippet.log(input[x] + ' and ' + input[input.length - x - 1])
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<input id="check" onchange="check()" />
```